# Is there a way to have an external authentication in Blazor without use of Database?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, saml-2.0, blazor-server-side

So essentially I have a Blazor server-side application. I am trying to add an external authentication using Azure AD SAML. I am using `Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2` package for the external authentication. I am not as familiar of different authentication methods in ASP.NET or Blazor.

I used Blazor server-side template for docker linux container that has Authentication setup to Individual account, and I added Azure AD SAML as external.

Here is how my `Configure Services` looks like inside of `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            this.LoadConfigurations();
            services.AddDataProtection();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddElasticsearch(this.Configuration);
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddSaml2("AAD", "Azure AD", options =>
                {
                    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("spn:" + this.Configuration["AzureAD:EnterpriseAppId"]);
                    options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri(this.Configuration["AzureAD:ReturnUrl"]);
                    options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                        new IdentityProvider(
                            new EntityId(this.Configuration["AzureAD:AzureADId"]), options.SPOptions)
                        {
                            LoadMetadata = true,
                            MetadataLocation = this.Configuration["AzureAD:AppMetadataUrl"]
                        }
                        );
                });
        }
```

Here we use SQLServer database and store user identities? The application uses generic Login Page:

[image: Login]

In my use case all I want is to authenticate users through Azure AD. I do not want them to create and use local accounts, nor do I want to have any local database. I looked everywhere and was not able to find solution that does not use the database. Can someone help me find the right direction?

Comment: The default project uses `Identity` as the authentication provider, with the default UI that has a login piece to it. You can override those views and remove those pieces that you don't want to show.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean default Blazor server side project with individual accounts authentication? I do not see the exact views inside of it, in particular the screenshot I posted.

Comment: I have found the answer about overriding UIs like you said. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-full-identity-ui-source
However, I still not sure how to remove Database dependency. As I understand the Identity is constructed with Database, without it it doesn't construct and runtime.

Comment: I took a look through the Saml2 library and without digging into it deeply I cannot immediately tell if it requires Identity or not. You can try playing around with `            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`. In their one example, they do have it configured to use Identity via https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/develop/Samples/SampleAspNetCore2ApplicationNETFramework/Startup.cs

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this? I am trying the same thing and there is not much info about it on the web.

Comment: So this is not a full solution. But for me I decided to just use in-memory database as  a workaround. It is no perfect as that still consumes memory for it, but it worked.