# Using Saml with Azure AD using Blazer Web assembly

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to use .NET core Blazer webAssembly client UI from main() and authenticate with Azure AD using SAML with the following code, but getting error. can't figure this out one issue below. any clue is appreciated

there was an error trying to log you in: 'Cannot read property 'redirectUri' of undefined'

OIDC works fine.

Below is my code called from Main in  Program.cs

```
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorWASMAuthApp.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
            .CreateClient("BlazorWASMAuthApp.ServerAPI"));
```

builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(); builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore(); builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddSaml2(options =>
    {
        // builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior);
        //APP Registration keys Will be moved to Json in subsequent story
        options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("https://localhost:5001/saml2");

        //options.SPOptions..Add("https://localhost:5001/saml2/API.Access");

        options.IdentityProviders.Add(
            new IdentityProvider(
              new EntityId("https://sts.windows.net/{Clientid}/"), options.SPOptions)

            {

                //SingleSignOnServiceUrl = signinURI,
                MetadataLocation = ...federationdataxml?clientid={clientid}"


            });

        ;
    })

      .AddCookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

The most [common errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0#troubleshoot) as per ms docs are caused by incorrect configuration

> Depending on the requirements of the scenario, a missing or incorrect
> Authority, Instance, Tenant ID, Tenant domain, Client ID, or Redirect
> URI prevents an app from authenticating clients.
>
> Running the app at a different port than is configured in the Redirect
> URI of the Identity Provider's app registration.

Please check if the cause is  missing **return url parameter** in configuration in your code provided:

`options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/authentication/azurecallback");` which comes **after**

```
options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("https://localhost:5001/saml2");
```

else check  **Portal side** configurations.

While registering  API , redirect uri is set as web and its field is left empty and api is exposed from Expose api .
But When registering **client app** , redirect uri must be set    ,hope you have done so.
client app > go active directory  b2c >give name >select  supported account>redirect uri >select **SPA**-give redirect ur like https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback

> (format  of uri : https://localhost:{PORT}/authentication/login-callback.)

This 'authentication/login-callback' must be present in your code configuration too.

From [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-token-scopes)

> NOTE: The default port for an app running on Kestrel is 5001. If the
> app is run on a different Kestrel port, use the app's port. For IIS
> Express, the randomly generated port for the app can be found in the
> Server app's properties in the Debug panel. Since the app doesn't
> exist at this point and the IIS Express port isn't known, return to
> this step after the app is created and update the redirect URI. A
> remark appears in the Create the app section to remind IIS Express
> users to **update the redirect URI**.

So Check  the port running and update the redirect uri if not done.

**References:**

1. [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419568/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-external-authentication-in-blazor-without-use-of-datab)
2. [Reference 2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/how-to-build-a-blazor-web-app-with-azure-active-directory-authentication-and-microsoft-graph/)
3. [Cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-1)